# Unmount of /system failed : no such volume

Tags: flashing

Whenever I tried to flash any custom rom except 360 OS IN coolpad note 3 lite, flashing process ends with
"Unmount of /system failed : no such volume". I am using twrp for flashing roms. If I tried to restart my system, It stucks in bootloop. Now I am 
stuck in twrp mode.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Agreed. I'm voting to close the question as off-topic.